# How to suppress noise in my circuit

Tags: mosfet, noise, switching, load

[image][image]

I illustrated what my circuit do as you see. Switching frequency is 800 Hz. When I increase the load, a noise is heard from my circuit.

Here is my drain oscillocope view in frequency domain. What can I do to eliminate this noise?

Maybe I need a low pass filter but I couldn't know where I'm gonna put.
[image]

Comment: A noise is *heard*? That requires something to mechanically vibrate. The number one suspects for that are coils / transformers. Maybe your power supply? Hint: you can often figure out where noise is comming from by improvising a stethoscope: put a well-isolating pen in your ear (carefully!!) and press the other end to components on the board.

Comment: It could be some ceramic cap as well.

Comment: 800 Hz is in the audible spectrum, maybe choose a higher switching frequency so it becomes inaudible?

Comment: What's your decoupling situation?

Comment: @HarrySvensson 800 hz is mandatory. I don't want to hide problem just need suppress.

Comment: Guys 1uF over load cause  that noise. I put that to prevent inductive peaks while switching what i am gonna do now. @Chupacabras

Comment: @ismailkarakaş Try to use different type of capacitor, say electrolytic. Ceramic caps are known for piezoelectric effect, and you operate at audible frequency.

Comment: @ismailkarakaş If by inductive peaks you mean overvoltage on your MOSFET during turn-off, maybe consider moving the cap and make a turn-off snubber instead?